# JDBC MSSQL with Logsatsh to connect to Montoring DB

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, logstash, elastic-stack, mssql-jdbc

I have installed logsatsh 7.2 and I'm trying to configure a data fetch from Solarwinds DB.
I'm using the below Logstash configuration:

```
    input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://SOLARWINS:5674;databasename=Orion_DB;integratedSecurity=true"
        jdbc_driver_class =>  "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        jdbc_driver_library => "/etc/logstash/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar"
        jdbc_user => "logstash"
        jdbc_password => "pass123"
        statement => "SELECT * from events"
    }
}
output {
          elasticsearch { hosts => ["10.26.67.29:9200"]
                index => "swdata"
          }
          stdout { codec => rubydebug }
       }
```

and I'm getting an error that says:

```
[2020-01-08T01:57:19,264][ERROR][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] Unable to connect to database. Tried 1 times {:error_message=>"Java::ComMicrosoftSqlserverJdbc::SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:ef93944c-9f83-44d3-a370-254903b671ef"}
[2020-01-08T01:57:19,265][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline    ] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Pipeline_id:sw
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc jdbc_user=>"sa_logstash", jdbc_password=><password>, statement=>"SELECT * from events", jdbc_driver_library=>"/etc/logstash/mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar", jdbc_connection_string=>"jdbc:sqlserver://SOLARWINS:5674;databasename=Orion_DB;integratedSecurity=true", id=>"3c6c347831ec1a9a964da106925ef193a86d1d52adf190f9bd046d6b408e3e2b", jdbc_driver_class=>"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_52f36adf-96b9-44a1-8e8c-40b2f009ebd2", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, jdbc_paging_enabled=>false, jdbc_page_size=>100000, jdbc_validate_connection=>false, jdbc_validation_timeout=>3600, jdbc_pool_timeout=>5, sql_log_level=>"info", connection_retry_attempts=>1, connection_retry_attempts_wait_time=>0.5, parameters=>{"sql_last_value"=>2020-01-07 12:18:53 UTC}, last_run_metadata_path=>"/usr/share/logstash/.logstash_jdbc_last_run", use_column_value=>false, tracking_column_type=>"numeric", clean_run=>false, record_last_run=>true, lowercase_column_names=>true>
  Error: Java::ComMicrosoftSqlserverJdbc::SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:ef93944c-9f83-44d3-a370-254903b671ef
  Exception: Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError
```

Now, 
My Solarwinds is in windows and my Logstash is in Linux. I see this can be a potential problem.
But I dont entirely understand what I can do about this.

What do I need to change in my config file to enable connection?

**UPDATE:**
I changed the connection string to

```
 jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://STRPROAG01:32452;databasename=Orion_DB;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos"
```

New Error Log:

```
[2020-01-08T04:36:56,186][ERROR][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] Unable to connect to database. Tried 1 times 
{:error_message=>"Java::ComMicrosoftSqlserverJdbc::SQLServerException: Integrated authentication failed. ClientConnectionId:dd8a0cae-cbc1-4a8b-94aa-a3186e810e94"}
    [2020-01-08T04:36:56,189][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline    ] ntAuthInit(com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/KerbAuthentication.java:125)
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the JDBC Sql connection document, can you try providing the username and 
    password in the connection string query as shown below:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://servername=server_name;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;userName=****;password=****

Please refer the doc :
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

```
please try and let me know , if the issue still persists.

Thanks.
```

Comment: The issue still persisted. However, I set integrated security to false, to allow only an SQL authentication, with No windows/Kerberos level authentication.